# Best way to protect Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, security

I'm setting up a mongodb, and wondering if there is one simple and efficient way to secure my database. I've been trough some old post from 2012, it might be some better options at this time.

The [Shadow Server](https://mongodbscan.shadowserver.org) project scans for all mongo databases running on port: 27017, and lists insecure databases running all over the world.

I've seen how authentication works with user and password, but I would like to avoid it at this moment, for development simplicity I need to connect to it without setting up an username and password - (Is it the best way?)

What could be the alternatives?

Comment: Firewalls help a lot here, even when using username and password auth but you could tunnel your traffic to specific IPs

Comment: Configuration of database systems is a topic for https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks all, sorry for placing the question in the wrong place @Philipp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to secure your MongoDb instance is by limiting access to your local network. However, if you have to expose it to the outside world, you should consider running MongoDB with authentication and limiting access to certain IP ranges.

Comment: That was what I was looking for, now I have configured iptables firewall for my mongo accepting only my connections / ip's. When in production ill set up a user/password and limit access to local network, if the application stays in the same ambient. Thanks all!